# Plus or minus in footnote that doesn't add extra line

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I'm attempting to use the +/- sign within a footnote, however when I use the following command it creates a line break and takes up a lot of extra space.

I believe its because I'm putting it in as an equation within a footnote, however I'm not sure how to go about getting the symbol any other way...

```
~\footnote[1]{The threshold was set at \[\pm\]20\%}.
```

Comment: Why not simply use `$\pm$` or `\(\pm\)`?

Comment: Inexperience with LaTeX mostly...

Comment: Why do you use the `~` in front of `\footnote`? Footnote numbers should follow the text without a printed space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply replace the displayed math-mode `\[ \]` by an inline math-mode (between `$` symbols):

```
~\footnote[1]{The threshold was set at $\pm20\%$}.
```

Comment: I'd probably put the `20` here in math mode too